# How to recursively swap top element of stack to the bottom

Tags: java, recursion, stack, reverse, swap

I am wondering how to recursively swap the top element of a stack to the bottom.
The stack should end up looking like this:

```
4 (top)
3
2
1
```

becomes

```
3 (top)
2
1
4
```

I figured out the recursive function to reverse the order of the stack. But I'm stuck on trying to do it for only one. I am assuming it has something to do with altering the base case.

```
public void roll() {

    if (!isEmpty()){
        E temp = getBottom(this);
        roll();
        this.push(temp);
    }

}

private E getBottom(LinkedStack<E> p){
    E temp = p.pop();
    if (p.isEmpty()){
        return temp;
    } else {
        E temp2 = getBottom(p);
        p.push(temp);
        return temp2;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually prefer doing it iteratively, but since you've specified recursively, you could do it by reversing the stack and then partially reversing it again. Even simpler is to just directly send the top element to the bottom:

```
public void sendTopToBottom() {

    if (!isEmpty()){
        sendToBottom(pop());
    }

}

private void sendToBottom(E victim){
    if (isEmpty()){
        push(victim);
    } else {
        E temp = pop();
        sendToBottom(victim);
        push(temp);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to swap the top two elements and then leave the second top element outside, after swapped all elements then push that element back. For example:

```
    public void roll(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        if (stack.size() <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        Integer top1 = stack.pop();
        Integer top2 = stack.pop();
        stack.push(top1);
        roll(stack);
        stack.push(top2);
    }
```